# Доступ к элементам ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавлял элементы в ListBox так -

```
listBox1.Items.Add(стринг переменная);
listBox1.Items.Add(стринг переменная2);
listBox1.Items.Add(стринг переменная3);
```

Как мне теперь получить доступ к элементам которые я добавил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для доступа к элементам массива используется обычный способ с индексацией например

```
var value = listBox1.Items[index];
```

можно так же использовать foreach

```
foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
{
   // item - делаем то что нам надо
}
```

или for

```
for (var i=0;i<listBox1.Items.Length;i++)
{
    // listBox1.Items[i] - делаем то что нам надо
}
```

или Linq

```
var items = listBox1.Items.Where(a=>a.Contains("подстрока"));
```

Comment: Когда я пишу listBox1.Items[i] и ставлю точку у меня там вылезает только object методы equals, gethashcode, gettype, tostring и больше ничего нет

Comment: @jokelocker `listBox1.Items[i].ToString();` - вернет вам ваш элемент

Comment: @jokelocker,  тогда уточните вопрос, что вам в итоге надо? какой уровень доступа?

Comment: Вроде всё как мне нужно спасибо. Только в цикле for нету свойства Length, есть Count